# Recaptcha contact form 7 "status: spam" at Vue.js App

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, recaptcha, contact-form-7

I built a small Vue.js app that runs under a subdomain (same main domain as WordPress) and uses the axios package to submit a form to the contact form 7 rest API. Unfortunately I always get only "status: spam" back as a response. I have already set up a recaptcha for the Vue.js app and at the recaptcha of the WordPress on the main page I have also whitelisted the new subdomain.

If I turned off the Recaptcha it works as expected.

```
const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('customerName', this.formInput.customerName);
      formData.append('customerEmail', this.formInput.customerEmail);
      formData.append('customerPhonenumber', this.formInput.customerPhonenumber);
      formData.append('date', this.formInput.date);
      formData.append('privacy', this.formInput.privacy);

axios.post('https://MY_DOMAIN/wp-json/contact-form-7/v1/contact-forms/1347/feedback', formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
          this.result.status = response.data.status;
          this.result.message = response.data.message;

          if (response.data.status === 'mail_sent') {
            this.formInput.customerName = '';
            this.formInput.customerEmail = '';
            this.formInput.customerPhonenumber = '';
            this.formInput.date = '';
            this.formInput.privacy = 0;
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who's seeking for the answer to this particular question (I know it's super late to give an answer).

The reason why it's marked as spam as OP mentioned are,

1. We're not sending [WP Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) as part of submission as I see on OP code snippet, there's no WP Nonce being included. It's the best practice if you can include WP Nonce as part submission to any Wordpress-end (Rest-API etc), to avoid any issue. See the code below, where Contact Form 7 is also checking for WP Nonce.

```
    private function spam() {
        $spam = false;

        if ( $this->contact_form->is_true( 'subscribers_only' )
        && current_user_can( 'wpcf7_submit', $this->contact_form->id() ) ) {
            return $spam;
        }

        $user_agent = (string) $this->get_meta( 'user_agent' );

        if ( strlen( $user_agent ) verify_nonce() ) {
            $spam = true;
        }

        if ( $this->is_blacklisted() ) {
            $spam = true;
        }

        return apply_filters( 'wpcf7_spam', $spam );
    }

    private function verify_nonce() {
        if ( ! $this->contact_form->nonce_is_active() ) {
            return true;
        }

        return wpcf7_verify_nonce( $_POST['_wpnonce'] );
    }
```

2. Like OP mentioned on the last part, I suspecting that the Contact Form field that OP targeting is having Recaptcha field being included, in that case, we MUST includes Recaptcha response in that particular form - since Contact Form 7 do a check, whether or not there's a Recaptcha field and/or that field is NOT EMPTY. Below is the snippet, which checking for Recaptcha.

```
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_spam', 'wpcf7_recaptcha_check_with_google', 9 )
    function wpcf7_recaptcha_check_with_google( $spam ) {
        if ( $spam ) {
            return $spam;
        }

        $contact_form = wpcf7_get_current_contact_form();

        if ( ! $contact_form ) {
            return $spam;
        }

        $tags = $contact_form->scan_form_tags( array( 'type' => 'recaptcha' ) );

        if ( empty( $tags ) ) {
            return $spam;
        }

        $recaptcha = WPCF7_RECAPTCHA::get_instance();

        if ( ! $recaptcha->is_active() ) {
            return $spam;
        }

        $response_token = wpcf7_recaptcha_response();
        $spam = ! $recaptcha->verify( $response_token );

        return $spam;
    }
```

To solve that,

1. For WP Nonce, we can simply include that when sending the submission
2. For Recaptcha, we must somehow generate Recaptcha result, on my case, fortunately, I also have Recaptcha field, so I can just simply took that result and pass it on submission.
3. For future reference, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956314/4162090) - essentially it's the same like I've mentioned before

---

Good luck for future guy who encountering this issue! :)

Comment: For your solution on Recaptcha, it is a bit vague. Do you generate the recaptcha token from the frontend and somehow pass it to the backend or get the recaptcha token from the backend and somehow use it to make both ends work? Would appreciate a more detailed description, thanks!

Comment: Hi @HaydenNg - sorry, unfortunately, I'm not quite remember (I tried to check my past code/project, but seems it's already altered). Back then, I'm using CF7, it generates things around (fields etc), including recaptcha validation (see my answer above) and I think it's also generates the token (correct me if I'm wrong, I kinda forgot). Anyway, as far as I remember, I didn't generate it manually for both front-end & back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah you are right CF7 also generates the token but do you remember how to retrieve that token in the Frontend and pass it back on form submit? I'm assuming this is how it works.

Comment: As far as I remember, I didn't do that, so, sorry, I'm not sure how to advise you on this. But, if you want to, you can try to get all form-fields and see what's the difference between before and after you do recaptcha. I remember there's a hidden field `g-recaptcha-response` that being used behind the scene in wpcf7 function.

Comment: Hmm.. Unfortunately I was unable to find the hidden field `g-recaptcha-response` like you mentioned. But do you think that it makes sense that I should be setting up the recaptcha in the frontend and then only send it to cf7 in wordpress?

Comment: A bit unsure about it, since, CF7 should auto-generate your form once you call its shortcode, [something like this](https://contactform7.com/getting-started-with-contact-form-7/). Unless you create the form from scratch manually. But, I think you can setting up your recaptcha, just make sure you sent [WP Nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) when you sent your form, if you use WP as back-end.